# How can I run an automatic robo test on Android app? like the one on Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, android-testing

On the Play Store and on Firebase Test Lab I can run automated tests without writing any scripts, they just go through the app and try stuff for a few minutes.

How can I run this kind of test either from the command line or from Android Studio? I have about 10 different phones I would like to run it on.

Thanks.

Edit: just to be clear, I'm asking about the automatic robot test, where I don't tell it anything, it just tries stuff.

Comment: Create UI tests with Espresso Test Recorder  Click Run > Record Espresso Test.
In the Select Deployment Target window, choose the device on which you want to record the test. If necessary, create a new Android Virtual Device. Click OK.

Comment: But I don't have to do that for Firebase or the Play Store Console, it is like an automatic robot that just tries stuff. I want that automatic robot or is that something Google has made for themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 options :

1. You can record Robo tests through Android Studio. Crawler is part of Jetpack
   https://developer.android.com/training/testing/crawler
2. You can run Monkey tests through command line. Monkey is part
   https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey

Comment: That monkey test looks like what I want, but I'm guessing they have fine tuned it because I don't seem to get as much activity from it when I run it, but I'm still playing with all the options. Thanks.

Comment: You can actually configure all possible sort of events. Like % of click events, % of swipe events etc.

Comment: @casolorz Firebase Test Lab also uses crawler

Comment: @ZohaibAmir Do you mind explaining a bit further how to use crawler? I looked at their site, downloaded the app, and it runs the crawler apk on my phone but never even opens my app then says it found 0 crashes. I'm launching my installed package. If I launch the apk it says `androidx.test.tools.crawler.launcher.exceptions.AppPackageNameExtractionException: Failed to extract a package name for APK`. Thanks.

Comment: @casolorz After downloading the jar file, you need to run following command after connecting device:
`java -jar crawl_launcher.jar --app-package-name PACKAGE --android-sdk path/to/my/android/sdk`
Don't forget to replace the package name and path to sdk

Comment: Yeah that is what I'm running plus the device serial param and it opens the crawler on my phone but never opens my app. Do I need something inside my app for this to work?

Comment: The documentation says , "Specifies the package name of your app. Use this option when your app is already installed on the device and no re-installation is required.

This is a required flag if --apk-file isn't specified.
" Does that ring a bell?

Comment: Same as @casolorz, it did not work to me as well. I've followed the instructions (use existing app and my own app), but the crawler did not work as intented. Looking at the logs, I could see the message:"Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{androidx.test.tools.crawler/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner} from pid=25919, uid=25919 not allowed because package androidx.test.tools.crawler does not have a signature matching the target br.com.sampleapp". However, my own does not have signature.

Comment: BTW, I've found an interesting link that provide more details about App Crawler:

https://android.jlelse.eu/test-robo-scripts-locally-useful-for-firebase-test-lab-pre-launch-reports-41da83d5769f

Comment: How to run App Crawler:
https://medium.com/@denysiakimov/how-to-run-android-app-crawler-testing-tool-a0d6f387e89e